# How do you share a Facebook photo album with people that don't want to register for Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

I recall seeing this option when I created my album, but I don't know how to get back to it.  If you email the photo album to a friend, it makes them sign up before they can view it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The correct way currently is via [Alex answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/20341/40) of going to the cogwheel and selecting share.

---

Previously

> <sub>Go to the album link by going to [My Uploads](http://www.facebook.com/home.php?sk=myuploads), and click on
>   the album you want to share. The link should be something similar to</sub> 
>    
>       <sub>http://www.facebook.com/album.php?id=[userid]&aid=[albumid]</sub>     <sub>Then scroll to the bottom of the page , there you should
>   find the public link</sub>
>
> > <sub>Share this album with anyone by 
> >     sending them this public link:</sub> 
> >     <sub>http://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.999737156697.2491284.13608786&type=1&l=a91b17b9fa</sub>
> >     <sub><sub>The above is mine , logout of Facebook and you will see you
> >     can access it. Also your [Album Privacy](http://www.facebook.com/privacy/?view=photos) should be set to everyone
> >     for this to work.</sub></sub>

Comment: When I send this public link to friends who are not on facebook, and they click on the link, is it sure that in return they won't receive any e-mails from facebook inviting them to join? I mean since they receive my e-mail (I could send it from an account I don't use to sign in to FB, of course) with the link and their addresses are in this e-mail? Sorry if that sounds paranoid but I really would like to avoid "spamming" some of my friends who are against a FB membership.

Comment: @Ines no it's just a normal link. You can try checking it in an Incognito window or logged out. Sending it from email will be no different

Comment: This link appears to have disappeared.

Comment: Nowadays, you have to click on *Share*, and then you will get the public link.

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to your profile
2. Go to your photos
3. Go to Albums
4. Go to the respective album
5. Click on the cog wheel in the upper-right side of the album
   [image]
6. From the drop-down menu, click on **Get Link**
7. Send the link from the modal window to anybody you want
   [image]

**You don't need to set the album's privacy to public.** That link gives anybody who has it the possibility to see the album.

---

Previously:

1. Go to your profile
2. Go to your Photos
3. Go to the respective album
4. Scroll down to the bottom of the album
5. Copy the link appearing there: [image]
6. Send that link to anybody you want

Comment: This isn't working for me anymore. I tried with incognito and the link sends me to a generic signup page. Can anyone confirm this still works?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator it works

Comment: @phwd I tried the "With timeline" process again just now. If I open the link that I get in Step 7 with a Chrome incognito window (no cookie for Facebook login), the link wants me to sign up for facebook. I'm downvoting until someone clarifies.

Comment: Here's the format of the link I get: https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.xxxxxx&type=1&l=xxxxxx

Comment: @Fuhrmanator do you have a screenshot of this generic page

Comment: @phwd Here's a test album: https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10200203086304239.191465.1364462094&type=1&l=3be9588ec1 It leads to this page (in IE also): http://postimage.org/image/6r1c3yx8r/

Comment: It could be a bug, because their help page recommends the same thing: http://www.facebook.com/help/124590517619792/ Or they cancelled this option and didn’t updated the help page.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator looks like a bug. The feature works with all albums in my profile. Best report it

Comment: @Alex it may not be a bug. It may be that Facebook simply now force people to sign up to view the album.

Comment: @phwd what is the sharing option you put on those albums? I have groups defined in my profile and limit access to certain groups. Maybe it has something to do with sharing options?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator custom, friends only, selected group, everyone, me, I have a variety on different albums. They all work

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @Fuhrmanator, and I think I figured it out. I tried my own account, which like phwd, I'm able to share ALL of my albums. But users, who have only recently been on Facebook can't. I got the idea through the Facebook help page, saying that new users on Facebook have less “rights” than other users. Things to improve your trust wordiness are: adding phone number, lots of friends, adding comments, etc. Hopefully, it will be over in a few months.

Comment: @HoogstudentengildeDeWesp that is a different problem. I want to share my wedding pics with a cousin who is not on Facebook and won't be signing up.

Comment: Still appears to be an issue. Having this problem for over a month now. The Share URL does not seem to work for people who are not on Facebook. I thought that was the point of the feature? :(

Answer (score 2):

Press "edit photos" then right at the bottom (underneath the "save" button) is the public link. Labeled as such.