# What is the way by which I can let the people see my photographs without logging in on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you share a Facebook photo album with people that don’t want to register for Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5297/how-do-you-share-a-facebook-photo-album-with-people-that-dont-want-to-register)

I don't have/want a dedicated "page" currently, but I do wish to let the people see my photographs without logging in on Facebook?

How can I do this?

Comment: You used to be able to share albums to anyone, but I can't find the link on the revamped pages.

Answer (score 3):

You should make your Facebook albums public, so that everyone could view them. If the albums are public, then they will be visible in searches and all you would have to do to share the photos would be to share the link.

1. Select the album you want to change the setting of
   [image: Step 1: select the album you want]
   or
   [image: sometimes it comes at the bottom]
2. Change the privacy settings by clicking on the globe icon (*sometimes the globe icon/privacy icon comes below the image also*)
   [image: step 2: change the privacy settings to public]

You should also consider uploading them to [Picasa](https://picasaweb.google.com/home) or [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/).

Comment: *"You should make your facebook albums public"* I actually have all my things on FB as public. Which particular setting are you talking about? Please show the screenshots.

Comment: @AnishaKaul Screenshots uploaded

Comment: I checked out this setting. Mine is already public. Still my photos are NOT visible when I am not logged in.

Comment: did you check if that individual photo your trying is public or *friends only*

Comment: Individual photos don't have the option of `public` etc. At least I couldn't find this option on individual photos. :( Will see again today though.

Comment: individual photos have that at the bottom of the photo or on the right side.

Comment: okay, I''ll check and report back.