# Share your Facebook photo album with non-Facebook users

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, facebook-photos

In the 2000s (before 2010) Facebook would allow you to get a direct URL to one's own Facebook album that could be emailed and shared with non-Facebook users. People have asked this question before like in this [question in 2010](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/5297/208898).

It is now 2019, and those old answers no longer work. Does Facebook still allow that or any other way to share your albums with non facebook people? I want to share my photo album with some of my contacts on WhatsApp and Instagram.

Comment: Somebody down voted. Why? Do I need to improve my question? Is my question not relevant? I feel this is a valid and relevant question; especially since Facebook use to provide a solution to this use case before. If you want to down vote then please leave a comment with the reason you down voted.

Answer (score 1):

Privacy changes, scraping and general "aggressive" signup flows to Facebook have caused sharing public photos to be a slightly annoying process however it's still possible.

As long as the album is "Public" non-Facebook users will see it.

[image: Privacy option]

Yes, you will still see the dialog asking a user to sign up you can call it aggressive signup flows or whatever you want, as long as you close that you will see the album.

Click "Not Now"

[image: Signup flow]

So the link to an album with Public setting looks like

```
https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.ALBUM_ID&type=3
```

Where ALBUM_ID is the ID of the album you want to share.
To get to this easy, you can choose clicking share (at the bottom where like, comment and share are shown) then choose "Share in a Private Message" to get a way to copy the link.

[image: Option for getting the share link]

And then copy the link

[image: Manually copy the link address]

---

There are no other options as far as I know, maybe embedding the photos but website style development questions are out of scope here.
The share by email option no longer works (it was removed)

I know it's not like the options offered in the past but that's just how it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Photos > See All > Hover mouse over the album you want to share with others and right click your mouse and select "copy link address"

Comment: Those links don't work if you are not logged into a facebook account. The old links used to work for non users.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers seem to work as of 2022. Facebook has continued removing various highly useful features because reasons, apparently.

Comment: I confirm. I made a public album, copied/pasted the link to another browser and the only thing I can see if the album title. Not the photos in it.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the album and copy the address straight from the address bar.  As long as it's public, anyone can view it at the same link you do.  The address starts with `https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.`